# Out of $25$ workers, can each one be able to work with exactly $5$ others?

Tags: graph-theory

So a question I should be able to solve for my exam discrete mathematics goes like this:

In a company of $25$ workers there is a bad atmosphere, it is known that some pairs of  workers can't work together. Out of $25$ workers is it possible that every worker can work together with exactly $5$ other workers.

This is supposed to be solved using graph theory, but other ideas are welcome to.

Comment: Look up the handshaking lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describe the scenario as a graph with each worker as a vertex and an edge between two vertices if those workers are capable of working with one another.

How many vertices are there?

What is the degree of each vertex?

Is this possible?  Why or why not?

> Is it possible for there to be an odd number of odd degree vertices?

$~$

> "Handshaking lemma"

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If it was possible, consider the graph whose vertices are the workers and whose edeges join the pairs of workers who can work togother. The sum of the degrees of all vertices is $125(=5\times 25)$. But this number should be twice the number of edges, right?!

Comment: it has an odd number of vertices with odd - degree ,you imply that there is not such a graph , right?

Comment: @brucebanner Yes, that's it.